# Is M totally bounded?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

$M=]0,1[$ $ \,  d:M \times M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $ \, (x,y) \rightarrow \mid \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y} \mid. $

I'm trying to figure out if this is totally bounded.  I'm trying to find a set $X$ that satisfies the definition. So does this

$$X=\{ \frac{2\varepsilon}{x}\mid x \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

set do the work?  It works for $d(x_i,x_{i+1})<2\varepsilon$, so I feel like it should be enough, but I'm not sure about anything anymore.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think it is even bounded? To me it is isometric to the Euclidean $(1,\infty)$, which is definitely not bounded. Also, total boundedness requires the number of balls that you use to be *finite*. If you allow it to be infinite then you no longer even necessarily have boundedness, much less total boundedness.

Comment: oh, I see. I didn't know the number of balls had to be finite. The definition makes much more sense now. Thanks!